# How to properly host a shiny app on a shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I installed a Shiny Server on a CentOs server, installation went smooth and I'm abble to run the demo app.

I now would like to host my app but I'm not sure about the right way to do it.

First I just have a ui.R file (I don't have ui.R and server.R, just ui.R) which is composed as follow:

```
packages importation
some R code

ui <- bootstrapPage(
some ui side code
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
some server side code
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I moved this file and some needed csvs file first to

> /opt/shiny-server/samples/novamente/

In this case I'm just getting a error

So I moved my files to

> /srv/shiny-server/novamente/

But when I'm trying to access it through web i can only see a list of my files:[image]

Comment: rename ui.R to app.R or split the code into two files ui.R and server.R

Comment: thanks for your answer, now when im trying to access the app im getting "ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification." problem is no log file is created for this app in /var/log/shiny-server

Comment: I had a problem with plotly, everything works fine now, many thanks for your help @BigDataScientist